# Powerpoint AddIn

Tags: c#, office-addins, powerpoint-2010

I am new to powerpoint add in and looking to add custom task pane.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane(v=vs.110).aspx

from Above link you can add custompane by using

```
  this.CustomTaskPanes.add()
```

I cannot find CustomTaskPanes in the intellisense when trying to do it from ribbon control click.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CustomTaskPanes collection is a property on the ThisAddIn class. 
So, you will be able to access it within the ThisAddIn_Startup method using the "this." syntax. If you're not seeing the collection in intellisense/autocomplete.

The issue may have arised due to some possibilities like :

1. You're not using VSTO(Visual Studio Tools for Office) 2005 SE.
2. You're using VSTO 2005 SE but you installed on top of a previous VSTO v3 CTP which was not completely removed.
3. You're building an add-in for an application that does not support custom task panes (all the Office 2003 apps, Visio 2007).

Answer (score 0):

That's a sample code to create a "Log Pane" and load a control into it. It's defined as a new property of `ThisAddin.cs` class, so you can invoke it by `Global.ThisAddin.LogPane`

```
    private OfficeTools.CustomTaskPane _logPane;

    public OfficeTools.CustomTaskPane LogPane
    {
        get
        {
            if(_logPane==null)
            {

                //my winforms component to load into the pane
                var logViewerComp = new LogViewerComp();

                _logPane = CustomTaskPanes.Add(logViewerComp, "Log Pane");

                //makes the log component fill the all pane size
                logViewerComp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

                //sets the opening position of the pane into PPT view
                _logPane.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionBottom;

                //does something when the pane shows/hides
                //in this case refreshes the Ribbon to enable/disable
                //the toggle button status related to the pane
                _logPane.VisibleChanged += (snd, ev) =>
                {
                    Ribbon.Reload();
                };
            }

            return _logPane;
        }
    }
```

Note: when you create a Pane it belongs to the all app and it is shared between all presentations the user opens.